# Mock static function of a class

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am implementing one class X which has one method xyz() which uses static method abc() of a class A. This static method abc() takes return value of another static method of same class which takes 2 arguments. One is HTTPServletRequest object and other is value of one enum. I want to test functionality of my method xyz() of class X, for which I thought of using PowerMockRunner to mock xyz() method of class A. But I am facing problem here and not able to do so. 'Except' clause is not working and thus it is not returning value that I want it to return for normal test to proceed. Please advise.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(A.class)
public class DataProviderIntegrationTest {
@Mock
 private HttpServletRequest request;

 @TestSubject
 X x= new X();

 @Test
 public void testXyz() throws Exception {

 long customerId = 1;
 expect(A.abc(A.pqr(request, B.CUSTOMER_ID.getAttributeValue()))).andReturn(customerId);
 replayAll();
 Output output = x.xyz();

 Assert.assertNotNull(output);
 }
}
```

Comment: The best way to get some help is to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you think a method should have more than one implementation, even for testing perhaps it shouldn't be `static`.

Comment: you can try powerMockito

Comment: Yes, I am trying using powerMockito only, but facing this issue

Answer (score 1):

Although you are asking for how to mock a static method, I will give you an answer for your real problem. I think, you have in fact an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

So, as you are testing one of your methods, you have the opportunity to greatly improve your code under test. You obviously already realized that a static method can be a pain in testing. What to do?

Simple answer: Express the needed functionality with an interface!

I'll give you an example with some static methods from the Java runtime library. You can easily transport the mechanism to your code. Let's use the [`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) method which is static. The method that shall be tested:

```
final class MyClass {
    double myMethod(double multiplier) {
        double result = Math.random() * multiplier;
        return result;
    }
}
```

The call to the random functionality is in fact a dependency of your class where this code belongs to. So we first create an interface carrying this functionality:

```
interface Randomizer {
    double random();
}
```

Additionally, we create a first implementation for it:

```
final class DefaultRandomizer implements Randomizer {
    @Override
    public double random() {
        return Math.random();
    }
}
```

Now we can rewrite the class to:

```
final class MyClass {
    private final Randomizer randomizer;

    MyClass() {
        this(new DefaultRandomizer());
    }

    MyClass(Randomizer randomizer) {
        this.randomizer = Objects.requireNonNull(randomizer);
    }

    double myMethod(double multiplier) {
        double result = randomizer.random() * multiplier;
        return result;
    }
}
```

As you can see object of that class are now instantiated by providing them the needed `Randomizer`. The parameterless constructor is a simple way for providing a default one. It could be omitted, but then some other parts of your code must be changed, too.

And the test now becomes very easy. You simply create a test implementation of the interface `Randomizer` with which you instantiate the class. Doing so gives you full control over every aspect in the test method.

An example for such a test:

```
public final class MyClassTest {

    @Test
    public void zeroRandomShouldReturnZeroForPositiveMultiplier() {
        Randomizer zeroRandomizer = new Randomizer() {
            @Override
            public double random() {
                return 0.0;
            }
        };
        MyClass testObject = new MyClass(zeroRandomizer);
        double multiplier = 42.0;
        assertThat(testObject.myMethod(multiplier), is(0.0));
    }

}
```

The creation of the test implementation can be easily done with Mockito (I do it also for these purposes). But ... a mocking framework is not necessary for this scenario. In fact, this isn't called *mocking*, it is simple *stubbing*.

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed workaround solution of the problem, but in my case I cant rewrite the code in this way, since I am using someone else's library in which this static method is there. I am writing my own class which uses one of these static methods, and to test that I think I would have to mock this call only(correct me if I am wrong). Adding code snippet of test class for reference

Comment: My answer is not only a workaround. It is a big part in improving code quality. Additionally, all this takes place in your own code which has the call to the static method. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: yes, it is indeed a way to solve the problem. But I am curious now how this problem can be solved using any Mock library?

Comment: As far as I know, Powermock is able to mock static methods. But I am not familiar with it. As you explained you have some problem with exceptions while using this mocking framework. The shift I suggested is to not rely on a mocking framework but improve your design so that a mocking framework is nearly unnecessary (I use it only for having less code). The introduced interface and the new constructors enable you also to use this class in dependency injection containers - like in Spring or maybe in an EJB or CDI environment. Besides being testable now, this design has some more advantages.